# Unable to add to object prototype

Tags: javascript

I have this Object Literal:

```
var RPSPlayer = {....}
```

and I want to make new "children" from this object by using:

```
var player1 = new Player(randomPlay);
```

When I try to add a function to a `Player` prototype like this:

```
function Player(play) {
    this.prototype.play = play;
    return play;
};
```

I get an error.

`play` is a function returning a string which Player function gets as a parameter.

The problematic line is:

```
 this.prototype.play = play;
```

Comment: It's good to say what the error is.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ the error is obvouisly a "cannot set property play on undefined"

Comment: @Raynos Yep. And yet, posters should say what errors they're getting.

Comment: We start at RPSPlayer... and then get to Player ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simply:

```
function Player(play) {
    this.play = play;
}

Player.prototype = RPSPlayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

`var RPSPlayer = {....}`

and i want to make new "children" from this object by using:

`var child = Object.create(RPSPlayer);`

but when im trying to add function to player by prototyping using:

`RPSPlayer.play = function () { ... }`

it works!

Seriously though, use `Object.create` to create your instances and distinguish between own properties of instances and properties that belong on the prototype.

If you want an instance to have own properties then write to it

`child.play = function () { ... }`